seatd Issues with Wayland on FreeBSD
When trying to launch Hikari (A wayland compositor) on FreeBSD I get one of two errors. Either seatd tells me that running as root is forbidden (when I'm not root) and when I run seatd-launch hikari I recieve : [seatd/seatd.c:163] Socket file found at socket path /var/run/seatd.sock, refusing to start seatd exited prematurely
Any help at all is appreciated.

Is your user a member of the video group? If not, then you should make it one:
# pw group mod video -m [your_username]

